# dbcc checkdb cause my Availability Group to failover

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, dbcc

During maintenance plan on primary node of an Availability group, a client database has been found corrupted... 
After some investigation: SQL SERVER generate its DUMP STACK, this cause sql instance to freeze and the Availability group try to failover. This cause 10 minute of connection issue...

Is this the correct scenario for a maintenace plan on a Always on Availability groups?

Some logs below:

```
2017-03-27 09:39:41.27 spid228   DBCC CHECKDB (xxx) WITH no_infomsgs executed by musesa found 1 errors and repaired 0 errors. Elapsed time: 0 hours 1 minutes 6 seconds.  L'instantané de base de données  interne a le numéro séquentiel dans le journal du point de fractionnement = 000071f6:00014d65:0001 et le premier numéro séquentiel dans le journal = 000071f6:00014d63:0001.
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   **Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x00000014AF73ADD0
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   ***Stack Dump being sent to E:\xxx\SQLDump0020.txt
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   * *******************************************************************************
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   *
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   * 03/27/17 09:39:41 spid 228
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   *
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   * DBCC database corruption
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   *
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   * Input Buffer 94 bytes -
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   *     DBCC CHECKDB WITH NO_INFOMSGS;  
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   *  
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   * *******************************************************************************
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-27 09:39:41.29 spid228   * Short Stack Dump
2017-03-27 09:39:41.32 spid228   Stack Signature for the dump is 0x000000000000007B
2017-03-27 09:39:42.92 spid228   [INFO]    Identity     Begin     End |    State      Result   Error  Speculate Prepared LazyCommit ReadOnly |  Transaction   Database    ThreadId | ReadSet  WriteSet ScanSet Savepoint LogSizeRq | CommitDep TotalComm   Dependent 0   Dependent 1   Dependent 2   Dependent 3   Dependent 4   Dependent 5   Dependent 6   Dependent 7 |    Area  Location |

2017-03-27 09:39:48.56 Server  Windows Server Failover Cluster did not receive a process event signal from SQL Server hosting availability group 'SQLCL-AG1' within the lease timeout period.
2017-03-27 09:39:48.56 Server  Erreur : 19407, Gravité : 16, État : 1.
2017-03-27 09:39:48.56 Server  The lease between availability group 'SQLCL-AG1' and the Windows Server Failover Cluster has expired. A connectivity issue occurred between the instance of SQL Server and the Windows Server Failover Cluster. To determine whether the availability group is failing over correctly, check the corresponding availability group resource in the Windows Server Failover Cluster.
2017-03-27 09:39:48.56 Server  AlwaysOn: The local replica of availability group 'SQLCL-AG1' is going offline because either the lease expired or lease renewal failed. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2017-03-27 09:39:48.56 Server  The state of the local availability replica in availability group 'SQLCL-AG1' has changed from 'PRIMARY_NORMAL' to 'RESOLVING_NORMAL'. The state changed because the lease between the local availability replica and Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) has expired. For more information, see the SQL Server error log, Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) management console, or WSFC log.
2017-03-27 09:39:48.57 Logon   Erreur : 18456, Gravité : 14, État : 46.
2017-03-27 09:39:48.57 Logon   Login failed for user 'xxx'. Raison : unable to connect on database 'xxx' etc etc...

=====================================================================                
   BugCheck Dump                               
=====================================================================                

This file is generated by Microsoft SQL Server                       
version 12.0.5000.0                                
upon detection of fatal unexpected error. Please return this file,                 
the query or program that produced the bugcheck, the database and                
the error log, and any other pertinent information with a Service Request.             


Computer type is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz.                  
Bios Version is INTEL  - 6040000                           
PhoenixBIOS 4.0 Release 6.0                              
4 X64 level 8664, 14 Mhz processor (s).                          
Windows NT 6.2 Build 9200 CSD .                            

Memory           
MemoryLoad = 74%       
Total Physical = 32767 MB    
Available Physical = 8388 MB   
Total Page File = 39079 MB     
Available Page File = 13127 MB   
Total Virtual = 134217727 MB   
Available Virtual = 134068411 MB
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you research anything at all first? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2014/11/26/diagnose-unexpected-failover-or-availability-group-in-resolving-state/

Comment: Hello and thanks for your rapid answer.  I already read this article... I'm really surprise of this behavior. This means that we can't run dbcc checkdb on production server?  We don't want to produce a service disruption when the checkdb find a corruption.  I can't find if there is a way to deactivate the creation of the STACK DUPM